# Are generator expressions doing less work compared to list comprehensions?

Tags: python, optimization, lazy-loading, list-comprehension, generator-expression

While refactoring a piece of code, I noticed this:

```
if product_id in [c["id"] for c in self.data.load_products()]:
    # Do something
```

In turn, `load_products()` does an SQL query, and for every product:

- Performs some relatively CPU-costly operations and:
- Uses `yield` to return the products one by one to the caller.

As I understand the difference between a list comprehension and a generator expression is that in a case of a list comprehension, all products will be loaded from database and processed, even if the very first product is a match.

Thus, if I replace it by a generator expression like this:

```
#                ↴                                          ↴
if product_id in (c["id"] for c in self.data.load_products()):
    # Do something
```

it could improve the code by eventually making it do less work, that is once the match is found, the next products won't be loaded from the database, nor processed.

Still, I don't know Python very well to be sure.

Am I right? Would Python stop as soon as it finds a match, or both pieces of code would perform the same and load every product from the database?

Comment: generators produce results one at a time. List comprehensions produces everything at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of List Comprehension is to create a new list. So, it will stop only when it runs its course and prepares a new list. The `in` operator will iterate over the newly generated list and returns `True` if any of the items in the list matches the actual item being searched. For example,

```
>>> lc = [item * 2 for item in range(10)]
>>> lc
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> 4 in lc
True
```

In case of a generator expression, the `in` operator will invoke the  `__iter__` method of the generator and it will stop immediately when the item returned by `__iter__` call matches the actual item being searched. You can confirm that like this

```
>>> ge = (item * 2 for item in range(10))
>>> ge
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f498a85fd70>
>>> 4 in ge
True
>>> list(ge)
[6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

As you see here, the `ge` is iterated only till a match was found. The `ge` object when converted to a list after the `4 in ge` check, gives the rest of the elements produced by the generator expression.

So, Generator Expressions are better in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension will always run to the end and keep all results in memory.

A generator (expression or not) **can** short-circuit if used appropriately -- e.g `if product_id in <some generator>` would indeed cease as soon as a match is found, only run to the end if there is no match.